# Submit button gets truncated in ie7

Tags: javascript, css

I am planning to use Bruce Galpin's Google Plus style UI buttons on my website - 
           code.brucegalpin.com/google-plus-ui-buttons/

This works beautifully on Chrome, Firefox and ie8+. However on ie7, the submit button is rendered truncated.

```
<button class="action blue"><span class="label">Save</span></button>
```

I have created a jsfiddle with the HTML and CSS - http://jsfiddle.net/22S2N/

To see the output directly on a browser (on ie7) click here - http://jsfiddle.net/22S2N/embedded/result/

Can someone please guide me how to fix this in ie7

Comment: So many importants, very scary.

Comment: IE7 does not support inline-block.

Comment: Thanks for your response @epascarello. Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: Search this site for `IE7 inline block` AND do you really have a large amount of users using IE7? Seems like a waste of time.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello. I agree that the number of ie7 users is not large. However in certain cases,I've noticed that the text in the button gets truncated completely (in this example its truncated partially). That's why I'm trying to address this.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this answer provided by Bruce Galpin himself in the comments section of this demo page.
            http://code.brucegalpin.com/google-plus-ui-buttons/demo.html

"The button tag seems to be the issue, so if you wish to have the action buttons display in IE7 just use:

```
   <a href="#" class="button action blue"><span class="label">Save</span></a>
```

instead of

```
   <button class="action blue"><span class="label">Save</span></button>
```

Same applies to the icons and buttons, replace

```
  <button><span class="label">Button</span></button>
```

with

```
 <a href="#" class="button"><span class="label">Button</span></a>
```

A decent workaround. Thought others might find it useful.